# Azure SQL DB publishing: Statement 'CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY' is not supported for the targeted platform

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

I have a database project for Visual Studio with target profile set as SQL Server 2014. Currently I'm trying to migrate to Azure SQL DB. After changing target profile in project properties to *Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12* I'm getting error:

> SQL70015: Statement 'CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY' is not supported for the
>   targeted platform.

In the same time [official microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-symmetric-key-transact-sql) says this statement is available in Azure SQL.

I use Visual Studio 2017 + the latest version of SSDT installed. Are there any solutions available except for keeping Target Profile as SQL Server 2014 and deploying with *Ignore platform compatibility* option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for certs and symmetric keys against Azure SQL DB in SSDT has been complicated by concerns around the impact on data export/import scenarios. More information about this is available [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/05/12/recommendations-for-using-cell-level-encryption-in-azure-sql-database/):

Microsoft is planning SSDT to support CREATE CERTIFICATE and CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY for some time now. So hopefully on a future SSDT version these DDL statements will be supported.